# How to use two different versions of Owl Carousel in same page?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I want to use owl carousel beta version and stable version together on a page. Is there a way?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Simple answer: No. And why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am working on a project in which owl stable version is used, i need to use url hash navigation for the section a am creating. if there is a way to do that in Owl carousel Old version then it'll do..

Comment: If you are interested do [try this](http://vinayakjadhav.github.io/jR3DCarousel/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make sure both carousels have different IDs (or classes), the page loads the JS and CSS for both versions, modify the JS and CSS on v2 to look for a unique identifier since both versions use the same classes.